# How to print input tensor in Tensorflow object detection API?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, object-detection

I added landmarks of images as inputs of the model by encoding them in a string in tf_example_decoder.py. (Didn't find a better way to do it). Now I want to verity if I could successfully parse the string into landmarks and if the values are correct. Where should I do this step? Thanks

edit: Landmarks are a list of 2d float coordinates. Since the current input format does not support landmarks, I need to add them by myself. I didn't find an elegant way to encode and decode 2D arrays via tfrecord, so I concatenate all points into a string as a bytes_list_feature. I want to parse the string back to float points in tfexample_decoder.py. But I'm not sure how to print the input to verify if the inputs are correct.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow this question --- are landmarks points?  bounding boxes?  Did you follow the directions here to set up a dataset? https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/using_your_own_dataset.md

Comment: @JonathanHuang I added more info to the question. Thanks!